# Mysql query to get created and resolved defect group by month

Tags: mysql, group-by

The table I am using is like bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp   ,
  `resolved` timestamp  ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tickets` (`id`, `created`, `resolved`) VALUES
  ('1', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-12'),
  ('2', '2021-02-25', '2021-01-15'),
  ('3', '2021-03-10', '2021-03-22'),
  ('4', '2021-03-10', '2021-03-22'),
  ('5', '2021-03-10', '2021-03-22'),
  ('6', '2021-03-11', '2021-03-22'),
  ('7', '2021-03-13', '2021-03-22'),
  ('8', '2021-03-13', '2021-03-22'),
  ('9', '2021-04-01', '2021-03-12');
```

Now I want a query to show me the table with columns like
`Month`, `NumberOfticketsCreated`, `NumberOfTicketsResolved`.

Here is what I tried so far but it does not return what I expect:

```
SELECT
   YEAR(`created`) AS y
 , MONTH(`created`) AS m
 , COUNT(`created`) as NumberOfticketsCreated  
 , count(`resolved`) as NumberOfTicketsResolved 
FROM tickets
GROUP BY y, m;
```

Comment: what is the expected result you want. Please add an output example to your question.

Comment: Incidentally, note that the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost entirely meaningless, and probably best omitted.

Comment: And it seems a little implausible that an issue might be resolved *before* it was created.

Answer (score 0):

Create table t1 with group by 'created'
Create table t2 with group by 'resolved'
then left join above two tables.

```
   select t1.y, t1.m, t1.NumberOfticketsCreated, t2.NumberOfTicketsResolved
   
   from
   
   (SELECT
   YEAR(`created`) AS y
 , MONTH(`created`) AS m
 , MONTH(`resolved`) AS n
 , COUNT(`created`) as NumberOfticketsCreated  
 , count(`resolved`) as NumberOfTicketsResolved 
FROM tickets
GROUP BY m) as t1

left join 

  (SELECT
   YEAR(`created`) AS y
 , MONTH(`created`) AS m
 , MONTH(`resolved`) AS n
 , COUNT(`created`) as NumberOdticketsCreated  
 , count(`resolved`) as NumberOfTicketsResolved 
FROM tickets
GROUP BY n) as t2

on t1.m = t2.m
```